# Oracle SQL select records from table where timestamp = today

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a table in oracle that has a column `created_ts` with type `timestamp(6) with timezone`

I want to select records where `created_ts` >= today. So for example if I was running the query today (2/20/17) I want all records where created_ts is newer or equal to 02-20-2017 00:00:00.

I've seen examples of doing it with `date` columns using `trunc(sysdate)`, but haven't seen how to do it with a timestamp+time zone column.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where created_ts >= trunc(current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend keeping datatype consistency, because trunc(a_timestamp) will transparently return a datatype of DATE.

So perhaps

```
where created_ts >= cast(trunc(current_timestamp) as timestamp)
```

is a more precise option.